# React Native Android - Error: "compileDebugJavaWithJavac"

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I have a problem I simply can't solve:
Problem:

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-code-push:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
```

Now this only happened after I installed another pakacge, Detox (greybox Testing), before everything worked fine

The error Code:

```
> Task :react-native-code-push:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
183 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 178 up-to-date
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePush.java:14: error: package com.facebook.react.devsupport.interfaces does not exist
import com.facebook.react.devsupport.interfaces.DevSupportManager;
                                               ^
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: package com.facebook.react
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ChoreographerCompat
  location: package com.facebook.react.modules.core
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ReactChoreographer
  location: package com.facebook.react.modules.core
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePush.java:153: error: cannot find symbol
            DevSupportManager devSupportManager = instanceManager.getDevSupportManager();
            ^
  symbol:   class DevSupportManager
  location: class CodePush
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
                latestJSBundleLoader = JSBundleLoader.createAssetLoader(getReactApplicationContext(), latestJSBundleFile, false);
                                                     ^
  symbol:   method createAssetLoader(ReactApplicationContext,String,boolean)
  location: class JSBundleLoader
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:112: error: method createFileLoader in class JSBundleLoader cannot be applied to given types;
                latestJSBundleLoader = JSBundleLoader.createFileLoader(latestJSBundleFile);
                                                     ^
  required: Context,String
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:156: error: cannot find symbol
                        instanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground();
                                       ^
  symbol:   method recreateReactContextInBackground()
  location: variable instanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:208: error: cannot find symbol
        ReactApplication reactApplication = (ReactApplication) currentActivity.getApplication();
        ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: class CodePushNativeModule
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:208: error: cannot find symbol
        ReactApplication reactApplication = (ReactApplication) currentActivity.getApplication();
                                             ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: class CodePushNativeModule
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:315: error: package ReactChoreographer does not exist
                                    ReactChoreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(ReactChoreographer.CallbackType.TIMERS_EVENTS, new ChoreographerCompat.FrameCallback() {
                                                                                                         ^
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:315: error: package ChoreographerCompat does not exist
                                    ReactChoreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(ReactChoreographer.CallbackType.TIMERS_EVENTS, new ChoreographerCompat.FrameCallback() {
                                                                                                                                                             ^
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:315: error: cannot find symbol
                                    ReactChoreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(ReactChoreographer.CallbackType.TIMERS_EVENTS, new ChoreographerCompat.FrameCallback() {
                                    ^
  symbol: variable ReactChoreographer
Note: /Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
13 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-code-push:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePush.java:14: error: package com.facebook.react.devsupport.interfaces does not exist
import com.facebook.react.devsupport.interfaces.DevSupportManager;
                                               ^
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: package com.facebook.react
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ChoreographerCompat
  location: package com.facebook.react.modules.core
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ReactChoreographer
  location: package com.facebook.react.modules.core
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePush.java:153: error: cannot find symbol
            DevSupportManager devSupportManager = instanceManager.getDevSupportManager();
            ^
  symbol:   class DevSupportManager
  location: class CodePush
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
                latestJSBundleLoader = JSBundleLoader.createAssetLoader(getReactApplicationContext(), latestJSBundleFile, false);
                                                     ^
  symbol:   method createAssetLoader(ReactApplicationContext,String,boolean)
  location: class JSBundleLoader
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:112: error: method createFileLoader in class JSBundleLoader cannot be applied to given types;
                latestJSBundleLoader = JSBundleLoader.createFileLoader(latestJSBundleFile);
                                                     ^
  required: Context,String
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:156: error: cannot find symbol
                        instanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground();
                                       ^
  symbol:   method recreateReactContextInBackground()
  location: variable instanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:208: error: cannot find symbol
        ReactApplication reactApplication = (ReactApplication) currentActivity.getApplication();
        ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: class CodePushNativeModule
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:208: error: cannot find symbol
        ReactApplication reactApplication = (ReactApplication) currentActivity.getApplication();
                                             ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: class CodePushNativeModule
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:315: error: package ReactChoreographer does not exist
                                    ReactChoreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(ReactChoreographer.CallbackType.TIMERS_EVENTS, new ChoreographerCompat.FrameCallback() {
                                                                                                         ^
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:315: error: package ChoreographerCompat does not exist
                                    ReactChoreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(ReactChoreographer.CallbackType.TIMERS_EVENTS, new ChoreographerCompat.FrameCallback() {
                                                                                                                                                             ^
/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java:315: error: cannot find symbol
                                    ReactChoreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(ReactChoreographer.CallbackType.TIMERS_EVENTS, new ChoreographerCompat.FrameCallback() {
                                    ^
  symbol: variable ReactChoreographer
Note: /Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
13 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-code-push:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

    at makeError (/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/user/gifts/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/user/gifts/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

As mentioned before, this only happened, after I have installed the Detox Package, which also makes some native changes. Before everything worked fine, therefore my confusion
If you need any more Information, pls let me know

Thanks a lot!